# Famous question calculation gone wrong?

Tags: bug, badges, view-badges

I noticed on SO the following:

[image]

[image]

---

I looked at five of these questions and all were well past the 10K marker: 23K, 52K, 23K, 15K and 48K

Looking at the user profile, I can see 15 gold badges but none appears here:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to an account merge. I've checked a [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) copy of one of the questions and it links to a different user than right now. Posts and comments are immediately migrated upon a merge, but badges are not (because e.g. you can't have two [Fanatic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/53/fanatic) badges). The user does not have any duplicate Famous Question badges, so this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

The empty badge list on their profile is likely to be a [caching issue](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/).